# How much of esp8266 flash can actually be mapped?

Tags: memory, embedded, esp8266

I was trying to link a program that has 200Kbyte of constant data.

I used the `__attribute__((section(".irom.text")))` attribute in an attempt to put it into the FLASH as I believe that the ESP8266 has  4MB of available flash.

Alas, the linker gives an error:

```
bin/firmware.elf section `.irom0.text' will not fit in region `irom0_0_seg'
```

The linker script that is used is what I got from platform IO, which is:

```
MEMORY
{
  dport0_0_seg :                        org = 0x3FF00000, len = 0x10
  dram0_0_seg :                         org = 0x3FFE8000, len = 0x18000
  iram1_0_seg :                         org = 0x40100000, len = 0x8000
  irom0_0_seg :                         org = 0x40220000, len = 0x5C000
}

INCLUDE "../ld/eagle.app.v6.common.ld"
```

Indeed the length of `irom` section is `0x5C000` (376 Kbytes) might be not enough for my code, constant array and the SDK.

So where are the promised 4Mbytes? Is it possible to map more of the FLASH?

Comment: The SoC itself has no on-chip flash.  What makes you think it has 4Mb?  The flash memory is provided by an external chip on the board or module - what is the precise part or board you have?

Comment: The flash available depends on your board--you can find out how much is there, though.

Comment: Possibly you have a _4Mbit_ (512Kb) memory?

Comment: @Clifford esp8266 modules usually come with external flash that is mapped into it's memory space. My device is nodemcu v3 and I am pretty sure it has 4MBytes. I will try to play with the linker script and increase the irom size. Maybe platformio had an error there.

Comment: https://docs.zerynth.com/latest/official/board.zerynth.nodemcu3/docs/index.html

Comment: @Artium : I know- that is what I said.  My point is the amount depends on the specific board or part.  You should add this information to the question rather than respond in comments.

Comment: The rest can be used for SPIFFS. Memory maps: https://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266_memory_map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I have figured this out.

It seems that the system parameters for a 4Mbyte module should be located at `0x3fb000`.

Thus it is possible to increase the `irom` segment size up to `0x3fb000 - 0x20000 = 0x3DB000` bytes.

Here is an example where I added 0x1000 spare bytes after `irom` end (just in case I missed something that I do not understand):

```
irom0_0_seg : org = 0x40220000, len = 0x3DA000 /* 4MB FLASH: irom begin untill system params start is 0x3DB000  */
```

It is also required to tell esp tool to put each section in the correct place in the flash (notice where `esp_init_data_default.bin` goes):

```
esptool -cd nodemcu -cb 115200 -cp "/dev/ttyUSB0" -ca 0x00000 -cf path/to/eagle.flash.bin -ca 0x20000 -cf path/to/eagle.irom0text.bin -ca 0x3fc000 -cf path/to/framework-esp8266-rtos-sdk/bin/esp_init_data_default.bin -ca 0x3fe000 -cf path/to/framework-esp8266-rtos-sdk/bin/blank.bin
```